# Insert query inside a loop with sleep() function not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a while loop with a `sleep()` function given below :

```
$employee = mysqli_query( $conn , "SELECT emp_id,emp_name FROM employee 
                      WHERE DATE(datetime) = '$date' " );

    if(mysqli_num_rows($employee) > 0){

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($employee)) {

            $emp_id        = $row['emp_id']; 
            $emp_name      = $row['emp_name'];  

            $number = mysqli_query( $conn ,"SELECT phone_number FROM emp_phone_number 
                                 WHERE emp_id = '$emp_id' ");

            if(mysqli_num_rows($number) > 0){

                while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($number)) {
                    sleep(2);
                  }

            }           
                mysqli_query($conn , " INSERT INTO `emails`(`emp_id`, `email`) VALUES ('$emp_id','hello') ");

        }

    }
```

The Insert query is working fine without the `sleep()` function. But when I enable the `sleep()` function it does not working. Please suggest me the reason.

Comment: Why do you want to use the sleep function in this case?

Comment: My first guess would be that there's some kind of timeout going on with the SQL query. It could be that you're the first person ever to attempt a `sleep()` in a MySQL query loop. Have you tried catching any exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

Where do you open Database connection using  **mysqli_connect()** ? It may be due to Mysql connection timeout as you have sleep of every 2 second. Try using **mysqli_connect()** before the **mysqli_query("Insert Query");** it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP `sleep` function takes a `int` argument which is seconds the execution should sleep.
You choose to sleep 2 seconds for each number of each employee.
I would think that the reason your code don't "work" is cause your execution time is so long due to the `sleep` call that you never see it finish.

Honestly, I cant see why you would ever want to use the `sleep` function in this case, and it looks quite strange that you just want to sleep a few seconds if a employee have a number or more...

Answer (score 0):

Several people have suggested timeout errors. That seems likely. I would try catching any exceptions to find out what is really happening

```
$employee = mysqli_query( $conn , "SELECT emp_id,emp_name FROM employee 
                      WHERE DATE(datetime) = '$date' " );
try{
    if(mysqli_num_rows($employee) > 0){

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($employee)) {

            $emp_id        = $row['emp_id']; 
            $emp_name      = $row['emp_name'];  

            $number = mysqli_query( $conn ,"SELECT phone_number FROM emp_phone_number 
                                 WHERE emp_id = '$emp_id' ");

            if(mysqli_num_rows($number) > 0){

                while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($number)) {
                    sleep(2);
                  }

            }           
                mysqli_query($conn , " INSERT INTO `emails`(`emp_id`, `email`) VALUES ('$emp_id','hello') ");

        }

    }
}
catch(\Exception $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```